# Should We choose Bigint instead of int In our Database table?

Tags: database, int, bigint

I'm very curious now that Should We must choose an Bigint primary key ID in our datatable.
The max value of Int type is 2^42. It's almost 20 billion.

Do we really store over 20 billion rows in our datatable. If that happens, i think it may have an terrible performance. Can you image you query such a big data in only one table.

So may be the int primary key ID could meet our requirement.

Comment: How do you generate those ID? Is it a problem if they are guessable?

Comment: 2^42 fits perfectly in a 64-bit integer,  why use bigint?